# Hot Water Knob Drips When Cold Water Is Turned On

Tags: plumbing, shower

I have an older shower set-up the 3 knob one (from left to right - hot, Diverter, cold).  I just replaced the valve-stem for all 3 due to leaking in the wall (where the valve stem connects to the "house" plumbing, sorry in advance for my lack of terminology).  Now, I do not have anymore leaking in the wall (I verified before posting this), but I have 2 strange things taking place:

> 1) The hot and cold knob twist more than triple what they did before I replaced the valve stems.  (Water pressure seems to stop at the original location, but the knobs are allowed to continue to twist)
>   
> 2) When the cold knob is twisted, water will drip from the hot knob

What is my plan of action for remedying this?

**EDIT**
This is an image of the valve stem that I got for my brand at my local box store

[image: Valve Stem Example]

**EDIT 2**

I can confirm the water is NOT leaking from either of these locations (both "behind the wall")

[image: Not Leaking Locations]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try tightening the packing nut on the hot side. If that doesn't do it you need to put in a new packing nut washer or rope. Here's what's happening: both valves closed it's not going to leak from either stem, hot valve open there's no pressure on the stem because all the water is going to the diverter and cold valve which will leak from the stem if the packing is bad, cold valve open water is going to the diverter and the hot valve and leaking out the stem.

Comment: Is the leak around the hot stem or is it from the threaded joint around the packing nut?

Comment: how would I check where the water is coming from?  Check my OP - I added an image, and it is NOT coming from either of these locations...both "behind" the wall...